ESLint Disable import into folders
The project has a folder structure
src
 --app
 --components
 --entities
 --modules
 --shared
 --widgets

I want to prohibit imports from the entities folder to all folders except modules
Previously I prohibited imports from the modules folder this way


    "no-restricted-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "patterns": [
          "modules/*/*",
          "!modules/*/index"
        ]
      }
    ],



This option is not suitable, if you also prohibit it in entities, then it will prohibit use in the modules folder, this does not suit me.
Please tell me how this can be done
